# How to read a condition flag in ARMv7 Thumb-2 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, armv7, thumb

I'm using an ARMv7 processor with Thumb-2 instructions.

I have executed an `ADD`, `SUB` or a `CMP`. Now I want to move the condition flag `LE` to `r2`. After this, `r2` should contain either `0` or `1`.

I've been looking through the Thumb-2 manual, but I haven't found a conditional MOV instruction or a special instruction to read the flags.

What's the most efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start a conditional block with an `ite` (if-then-else) instruction and then just use conditional assignments:

```
ite le        @ if-then-else (le)
movle r2, #1  @ if (le) then r2 = #1
movgt r2, #0  @         else r2 = #0
```

In general, you can use arbitrary conditional instructions in Thumb-2 if you prefix them with appropriate IT-instructions.  Read the manual for details.

Answer (score 3):

In ARM, (almost) any instruction can be predicated.  In thumb mode, that requires an `it` instruction to encode the predicate and pattern of negated or not for the next few instructions.

But in unified syntax the assembler can do that for you, without an explict `it`, I think.

e.g. `movle r0, #1` sets `r0 = 1` if the LE condition is true in flags, otherwise leaving it unchanged.  So you'd need a `mov r0, #0` first.

ARM32 doesn't have a set-from-condition instruction like x86's `setcc`.

AArch64 does: turning a flag condition into an integer only takes a single `cset` instruction.

This C source:

```
int booleanize(int x, int y) { return x<y; }
int booleanize_u(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a<b; }
```

compiles for ARM32 thumb with clang -O3 ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcgJsiAagBG6dE2zsCAL2wR5SgB7lFBxQE8AlIq4B2PotLYiEtosNcAzAGFzXh3YAIlwADACCZqrqmmw62AD6YhBibMIEwGzYmIosJilpGVkq1nYOTi6kbixe3sr%2BNraBMpbMsgCsMuRssiGd6LLegoKKohJSNjye9J1EPc0tANYgACy2AHQAnCEAbG0htssAHCGrIRuMTLLLnQC2IJNrPBtTtjzbW7bbniFty11z5H6Mk6whAIXIsxkvRacFgKAwNwADgQNBQqBAEcjUSAWKQbsBDjxwQAzFFEbCkUEQZQA5TyXHmWTTcgIm7YBQAeTYTEZUM6OBu7GAGgBhCcqCIBAAbthQXzyNhDNhUGJyUzOgZsJd5UwCMpSAzvFhpDJmURSAQ7qbmswhWghvxmHrQZAWuhEZL0KlZABaDmeRQ%2BgDqLCYTEDgrxEdQiLEXkCGFI5MMPpYbU8IPEkmk9Ba2o6/3lQLCACUALKKYCoVCKQ6PRQQfDEMgTKYmI1IlEU1ueayDfiCGZzSwtJCaHCkah5q63FaeNaeWyeZbPDa2NpbTzbeh/bpF2QgsEQ4fkWHINDoTuoyjUTFdyeoVgcWwhElkilUmnyulsBnqlmXmynLcryvTkAKQoivKYrKpKMpymBirKqqJrMpq2pgbq%2BqGsa/7mpa6p5na3ADo6WEuhAboegQXpyn6AbBqG4Y%2BkQuLAM4OR4tsywRkQSBiDcyjRrG8aJsmqbppmYw5tOMgFnuYFAoYhzbD63GKI%2BQqKOsIRrCEDZNiQpCtowigdli3a8MufYOnwQ58iOrQyNc5B3J487uZ5XneYWikHiIR6QtCiwrOsWy7PsRwnC%2B5xORmvl9P5QU2meqXwpeFloreGX3iABI8OQpJMOSlLUF%2BYE/n%2B1oATcQFEFyPKitggocFBYEwRK0qygCSEqmq1XoQCWEGqQ5hGjgeEWla0xERw9qkUI5HwFRnrejI9GBsSMqkKowjYKmwg3IGIZhlJ2YMLJ8kAkpKlqTxVY1nWPAGYQRkme2OWoiZNkLfZwXkGOLATlO5BLG0PB6c8K48G09AbOD5wXDOrkgHsCWAv5oLgslMKIBA6VXhSN4Yp9FJoE%2BwAvm%2BxUfmVtL0qN/6suy9UgU1LXCia7UEOKcHdfKvUof%2Bg06nqI1jbh1X4dNNoU/NAhkc6y2AtRtG%2Bv6x1MYGrGkOxSi4kdPo3HxAlCUbMZxp4CZkOJabxaM525k5V37jIymqepmkcNpel6S9zbGVZpnmferY8D9Ct2ceDmjuOZOUU5Ll3GjCmJcCAXY8OIXg5Dy4bDDcMI/QSMyPFqcY%2BnOOyTwnTl0Cf3zOQ21pF6KxAA%3D%3D)), revealing some stupid missed optimizations.  gcc is similar, making branchy code with no `-mcpu` or even worse than clang with `-mcpu=cortex-a53`.  Branchy is maybe not totally unreasonable on a simple microcontroller.

```
@@ BAD EXAMPLE, compiler missed optimizations

@ clang7.0 -target arm -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a53
booleanize(int, int):
    movs    r2, #0         @ movs is 16-bit, mov is a 32-bit instruction, I think.
    cmp     r0, r1
    it      lt
    movlt   r2, #1
    mov     r0, r2         @ wasted instruction because the compiler wanted to mov #0 before cmp
    bx      lr

booleanize_u(unsigned int, unsigned int):
    movs    r2, #0
    cmp     r0, r1
    it      lo
    movlo   r2, #1
    mov     r0, r2
    bx      lr
```

This is pretty definitely worse than `ite le` / movle / movgt from @fuz's answer, with 2 predicated instructions.

ARM-mode code-gen is more or less fine, where every 32-bit instruction word has 4 bits in the encoding for a predicate condition.  (The default with no suffix in the asm source is `al` = always.)

```
@ gcc8.2 -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a53
booleanize(int, int):
    cmp     r0, r1
    movge   r0, #0     @ a simple mov without predication or flag-setting would work
    movlt   r0, #1
    bx      lr

booleanize_u(unsigned int, unsigned int):
    cmp     r0, r1
    movcs   r0, #0
    movcc   r0, #1
    bx      lr
```

---

### AArch64 has `cset`, booleanization in a can.

```
@ clang and gcc make the same efficient code
booleanize(int, int):
    cmp     w0, w1
    cset    w0, lt            @ signed less-than
    ret
booleanize_u(unsigned int, unsigned int):
    cmp     w0, w1
    cset    w0, lo            @ unsigned lower
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

> I've been looking through the Thumb-2 manual, but I haven't found a conditional MOV instruction or a special instruction to read the flags.

You can use [`MRS`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihjcedb.htm), in order to copy the conditional flags to a register (i.e. `r2`).

> What's the most efficient way to do this?

So far, you have not included a requirement in which [conditional execution code](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes)  is not enough, so that is the most efficient way.

Comment: MRS is not really a good choice; it still takes one or two more instructions to shift/and the single bit you want into place.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the MRS instruction.